# pricefilter without WooCommerce

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, filters

I have custom post-type for products (with AFC filed price) I don´t have WooCommerce installed. But I would like to sort my products by price in a price filter. Any ideas how can I achieve that or someone can point me in right direction?

Comment: What code you have tried here?

Comment: I have not started yet looking for ideas ;-)

Comment: see this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212519/filter-by-custom-field-in-custom-post-type-on-admin-page

Answer (score 0):

You should `ACF` meta_query to filter custom post type by custom field.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

basic example:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'products',
    'meta_key'      => 'price',
    'meta_value'    => $value
));
```